# ngOnInit does not work due to build mode when using library

Tags: angular

If I create a library with the following configuration, install it on the application side, and inherit and use it,
If `ng build --prod=true`, `ngOnInit` will not be called.
If `ng build`, `ngOnInit` is called.

- `Angular` : 6.1.1
- `Angular CLI` : 6.2.9

It works if you quit the library and put the library source into the application.
However, I want to make it a library because I want to use it in common.

- library-sample-base.ts(library source)

```
export abstract class LibrarySampleBase implements OnInit {
    public ngOnInit() {
        this.InitPage();
    }
}
```

- library-sample.ts(library source)

```
export abstract class LibrarySample extends LibrarySampleBase {
    // no exist ngOnInit()
}
```

- sample.component.ts(application source)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sample',
    templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class Sample extends LibrarySample {
    InitPage() {
        // processing
    }
}
```

How can I get `ngOnInit` to be called even when `ng build --prod=true`?
Also, please let me know if you have any bug information.

Comment: Does it mean how you can use your library after publishing that?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

- library-sample-base.ts

```
    import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    export abstract class LibrarySampleBase implements OnInit {
        public ngOnInit() {
            this.initPage();
        }
        initPage() {
            console.log('Hi');
        }
    }
    export abstract class LibrarySample extends LibrarySampleBase {}
```

- app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { LibrarySample } from './library-sample-base.ts';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent extends LibrarySample {

      initPage() {
        console.log('Bye!');
      }
    }
```

*Bye* is shown as the log in the console. If I comment the `initPage()` in the AppComponent *Hi* is logged instead. So I think that works as expected.

- `Angular` : 7.2.12
- `Angular CLI` : 7.3.8

I'm using `ng serve --prod=true`  to try it.